# Stability of solution ODE with parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> For which $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ the solution $x=y=0$ is stability for
>   system of ODE:
>
> ```
> $x'=ax+y+x^2$
>
> $y'-x^2+by+y^2$
> ```

In some cases it's easy, because we can write $\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y'\end{bmatrix}=A\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}+g(x,y)$, where $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0}\frac{|g(x,y)|}{\| (x,y)\|}=0$, so the stability depend only on linear part of equation and we can get linear part counting the Jacobian matrix $A$ in point $(0,0)$.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & 1 \\ 1 &b\end{bmatrix}$

Next we are looking for eigenvalues, for example using characteristic polynomial:

$\chi(\lambda)=\lambda^2-(a+b)\lambda+ab-1$

Next it's easy to check that this polymonial has two real roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, because $\Delta=(a-b)^2+4$, so when $\lambda_1>0$ or $\lambda_2>0$ the solution isn't stability, using Vieta's formulas it's when

$ab-1<0$ or

$ab-1>0$ and $a+b>0$

We also know that if $\lambda_1<0$ and $\lambda_2<0$ then solution is stability, it's also using Viete'a formulas when $ab-1>0$ and $a+b<0$. The other case is when $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2>0$, it's when $ab-1=0$ and $a+b>0$ (the solution isn't stability).

Using this method we know the stability of solution in all cases except one, when $ab-1=0$ and $a+b<0$. So the question is: what we can do in this case? Is there any general method or it's tricky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the linear analysis when any of the eigenvalues of the linearization satisfies ${\rm Re\,}\lambda=0$. There is a general method for this case, which amount to finding *a central manifold* of the system and consider the dynamics on this center manifold. This is discussed in any more or less advanced text on dynamical systems (e.g., book by [Perko](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387951164)).